# How to mount component perpendiculary to PCB

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, pcb-assembly, mount

I'm designing small PCB(20mm*20mm) where I'm also limited by height of whole project that can't exceed 20mm. I have to place few [sensors](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optical-sensors/integrated-ambient-light-proximity-sensors/apds-9930) on the edge of the PCB but not facing up but facing out of the PCB so pads of sensors are perpendicular to the PCB.

Not the real design I haven't designed this part yet but describes what I'd like to do.
[image]

My question:
What is the usual way this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this done by using two PCBs: a smaller one to hold the component is mounted 90° perpendicular to the other one. Pads on the edge of the small board (both sides) soldered to the main PCB are used as support:

[image: PCB illustration]

These pads can consist of electrical connections, with additional redundant pads for strength. An alternative would be to use your choice of connector to interface between the two PCBs:

[image: board-to-board connectors]

Comment: Sounds good to me but I was hoping to solve it in another way. I'll wait a bit and then accept this answer.

Comment: For surface mount components, I'm unsure of another way.

Comment: @g_1_k added more information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with SMD on both PCB like the first figure shows, the second option is not available because of lack of space

Answer (score 1):

How about using these pins and soldering them on both PCBs?
Whats wrong with that?

[image: How about]